# I can't load a dict from a file using json.loads() in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to load a dict from a text file (file.txt) using `json.loads()`, I can save the dict, but can't get it. I have two scripts: one that saves the dict, and one that receives it. The script that receives will wait until it receives it, but when it does, it errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/receiver.py", line 9, in <module>
    d = json.loads(file.read())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here are my full scripts if that could help you

**RECEIVE.PY**

```
import json

d = {}

while True:
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
        if file.read():
            d = json.loads(file.read())  # It errors here
            file.close()
            print('Data found in this file !')
            break
        else:
            print('No data in this file..')

print(str(d))
```

**SENDER.PY**

```
import json
import time

d = {
    'Hello': {
        'Guys': True,
        'World': False,
    },
}

time.sleep(5)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(d))
    file.close()

print(d['Hello']['Guys'])
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying directly the filename using json.dump instead of json.dumps with the content itself?

Comment: I think you may want `json.dump()` instead of `dumps()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call `file.read()` twice, so the first one reads all the data then the second one won't yield any. Just store it to a variable:

```py
import json

d = {}

while True:
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()
        if data:
            d = json.loads(data)
            # you also don't need to close the file due to the with statement
            print('Data found in this file !')
            break
        else:
            print('No data in this file..')

print(str(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Aplet's answer above, you can `file.seek(0)` to reset the file object position to the start of the file after reading it:

```py
import json

d = {}

while True:
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
        if file.read():
            file.seek(0)
            d = json.loads(file.read())  # It errors here
            file.close()
            print('Data found in this file !')
            break
        else:
            print('No data in this file..')

print(str(d))
```

Aplet's answer is probably the better way to do it, but this is also a possible way.

For more info see the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: But note again that the `file.close()` is almost superfluous.